# getaddrinfo() returns 0 (success) but sets errno to EINVAL (22)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, getaddrinfo

I'm having problems with the following piece of code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


[...]
    struct protoent *tcp;
    struct addrinfo hint = {0};
    struct addrinfo *addrs;
    int             status;

    tcp = getprotobyname("tcp");
    if (!tcp)
        return  -EINVAL;
    hint.ai_family      = AF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_socktype    = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_protocol    = tcp->p_proto;
// errno is 0
    status  = getaddrinfo("localhost", "30002", &hint, &addrs);
// errno is 22
    if (status)
        return  -labs(status);
[...]
```

The problem is that although it works (I'm using this for a TCP communication which indeed is working), it's inconsistent:

`man getaddrinfo` says nothing about `errno`; instead it returns an error code.  Why may it be setting `errno` to `EINVAL` (22, Invalid argument) internally?

Comment: [getaddrinfo from glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c.html#getaddrinfo) is a long function and it uses errno internally in some places.

Comment: From `errno(3)`: "Its value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error"

Comment: In the link posted by @KamilCuk - the only place that jumps out as a likely source of `EINVAL` would be the call to `strtoul` at beginning line 1892. Which is the likely answer to your question *"Why may it be setting `errno` to `EINVAL`?"*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "localhost" :p

Comment: Ah-hah! Which points to a name-resolution problem with `/etc/hosts` `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter why it happens.  `errno` only has meaning to you when a function call fails in your own code, and that function is *designed* to use `errno` to report errors to you.  But that is not the case with `getaddrinfo()` in most situations.

`getaddrinfo()` may be (and likely is) using other functions internally to do its work, and if those functions fail then `getaddrinfo()` will silently handle them internally as needed.  If those errors are fatal to `getaddrinfo()`'s work then it will exit with its own error code returned to you as needed.

So, as long as `getaddrinfo()` *itself* is not reporting an error code to you than you simply can't rely on `errno` having *any* kind of meaningful value.  `errno` changing value is simply a *side effect* of `getaddrinfo()`'s internal implementation on your system.

The ONLY time you should be looking at `errno` after `getaddrinfo()` exits is when `getaddrinfo()` returns `EAI_SYSTEM`, ONLY THEN will `errno` have a meaningful value to you.

Comment: @AndrewHenle read that documentation again more carefully, it DOES document the use of `errno`: "*The getaddrinfo() function shall fail and return the corresponding error value if: ... [EAI_SYSTEM] A system error occurred; **the error code can be found in errno**.*"

Comment: Ahh, yes  I needed to read more.  Hmm, then I'd say it shouldn't be setting `errno` to non-zero values, per https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3

Comment: @AndrewHenle read that spec again more carefully: "***The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error**, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.*" The value of `errno` is *indeterminate* upon `getaddrinfo()`'s exit, unless it returns `EAI_SYSTEM`, that is the only documented case where `errno`'s value is meaningful when `getaddrinfo()` exits.

Comment: You can display any error with `getaddrinfo()` through `gai_strerror()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that only applies to `getaddrinfo()` own error codes. That is not the issue here.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what was intended, the question specifies a `0` return -- which from what I can tell means `getaddrinfo()` didn't set `errno` to begin with (it was set somewhere else). The intent of the comment was that if `getaddrinfo()` had failed and returned a non-zero exit, then further information can be obtained through `gai_strerror()`. (given that `getaddrinfo()` doesn't specify that it sets `EINVAL` at all)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin while that is true, it is completely irrelevant to the question at hand. The question is about why `getaddrinfo()` sets `errno` to non-zero when `getaddrinfo()` succeeds and returns 0. It has nothing to do with gleaming info about why `getaddrinfo()` returns non-zero if it fails.